# Move Woo-commerce variation sale price below actual price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to move the sale price under actual price for variation, I manage to do this for product summary part but not able to find any filter for variations.

Please see the image below.

[image]

I have tried this code but not worked, My code is working for Summery part

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'product_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'product_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function product_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
if(is_singular('product')){
// Main Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

// Sale Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ),$product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $prices );
$saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
$price = '<ins>' . $price . '</ins> <del>' . $saleprice . '</del>';
 }
   }
 return $price;
 }
```

Please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of css issue, you can style this using simple style tag

Change div classes as per your structure

```css
.priceMainWrapperDiv {
  display: table;
}
.salePriceDiv {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
.actualPriceDiv {
  display: table-header-group;
}
```